# Load content from another div on same page with on select from dropdown using jQuery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I know this is very common question and has multiple solutions already available but I am not able to find a proper solution to the question I had

I have a dropdown list, from where when user select the dropdown, the selection loads a div that is defined in the same page. It works fine, I have implemented it as follows:

```
<select id="selectMe">
    <option value="val1">opt1</option>
    <option value="val2">opt2</option>
    </select>

<div id="val1" class="group"> content1</div>
<div id="val2" class="group">content2</div>
```

**Jquery**::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.group').hide();
  $('#val1').show();
  $('#selectMe').change(function() {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  })
});
```

Now, this serves my purpose but takes a lot of time to load the divs as they contain huge data in them (Iframes, external calls) and page is taking lot  of time (almost half a minute) to load all the divs before displaying the first div which is pre selected, I am trying to use ajax as I understood that we can dynamically load other divs upon selection instead of loading them all at once on page load, i tried removing documet.ready() with windows.load function, but it didn't work. If i am missing something, can some one please help me out in solving the issue.

**Update1:**

The code works fine, i donot have any problem with it. I want to load only selected div at once instead of loading all the div's ( About 500) along with the page as it is taking lot of time to load because of huge data (div's -About 500 in number containing Iframe's).
 Instead I want to load each div separately dynamically only on selection or restrict load to only fewer number

**Update2:**

The div contains the data as follows:

```
<div id="val1" class="group">
 <iframe class="DZembed-table" src="//www.datazoa.com/data/table.asp?a=view&th=1A7400B7A3&dzuuid=423&uid=dzadmin" frameborder="0" width="800px" height="270px">Unavailable - Anderson County, Ks - Total Employment (not seasonally adjusted)</iframe>
```

/* Some text about 10-15 lines */

```
</div>
```

I have about 500 in number of such div's

for reference, please visit this page as example and it almost takes the same time to load the page I wanted to change

url: http://kansaseconomy.org/economic-indicators/total-nonfarm-employment-bls

Comment: What didn't work? Not sure why you would expect code shown to act differently. There's a disconnect in question between trying to load via ajax and switching the event trigger for the code shown. Not really clear what you are trying to accomplish with what is shown

Comment: Do you know what Ajax is? Ajax allows you to request/push data from/to the server without reloading the page.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question is unclear, i am pretty much new to this ajax. Don't get offended if i am wrong in something. Above code works fine i dont have any problem. The page is taking lot of time to load as the content div have pretty much huge data in them. Instead of loading all the div's at once, i want to load only the selected div. Any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want to load 500 iframes? To me that seems nuts. That's like opening 500 tabs in your browser.

Comment: I am trying to refactor it, any suggestions would be appreciated. I am not sure about the way to solve this or achieve a better solution to this.

Comment: What type of content are you inserting into these DIVs? Is it primarily text? Maybe a little bit of HTML? If so, I would have an endpoint as suggested by one of the answers below that would return the data for a DIV in JSON or HTML and then insert that into a DIV.

Comment: As updated in the question, it includes iframes and text alone (characters and some numbers) with very few images, nothing else. And yes i am planning to build a Json file for these iframes and return them to div's. I hope it works and also will look at the solution DanJGer provided in some time.

Comment: Do you need to show multiple DIVs? Or are you only ever showing one at a time?

Comment: I am just trying to show only one div at once. Json or database which one is better for this type of problems?

Comment: Well, 500 chunks of 10-15 lines of text doesn't seem that bad. You could skip AJAX all together and store each of the 500 chunks of info in a JavaScript object. [Here is a simple example with 3 chunks.](https://jsfiddle.net/ctpkLzz4/). You could easily scale this up to 500 and I don't think you'd see any problems and would be a big improvement over `<iframes>`.

Comment: Thank you I will look into the solution suggested and update the question with solution once I'm done

Comment: I will add my suggestion as an answer. Make sure to select an answer if it answer's your problem instead of adding your solution to your post. Otherwise answer your own question. Here's an [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/ctpkLzz4/1/) with 500 short chunks stored in a JS array.

Comment: Dude I will select the appropriate answer once I achieve it no worries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options that don't use `<iframe>`s. I wouldn't be too concerned about the footprint of your 500 text blocks as they're not super huge.

#### Option A - JS Store

With this option there's a lot less work when it comes to the markup. You don't have to manually or on the server create 100's of content DIVs. You simply re-use the same DIV.

```js
function createOption( value, text ) {
  
  var opt = document.createElement( 'option' );
  
  opt.value = value;
  opt.text  = text;
  
  return opt;
  
}

function buildSelect( options ) {

  var i    = 0;
  var len  = options.length;
  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  
  for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {    
    frag.appendChild( createOption( i, 'Option ' + ( i + 1 ) ) );
  }
  
  $list.append( frag );
    
}

var data = [
  "Quarter log Blimey hang the jib Davy Jones' Locker tackle boatswain squiffy. Shrouds American Main scallywag wench Blimey furl ye fathom. Holystone keel Pieces of Eight topsail come about Gold Road blow the man down fore. Overhaul mizzen gunwalls black jack long clothes weigh anchor fluke code of conduct. Take a caulk black spot brig fire ship gun long clothes jury mast tender. Ye yardarm to go on account jury mast grog blossom Plate Fleet broadside grog. Scuttle chandler belaying pin pirate gaff hulk pressgang Spanish Main. Topmast chantey crimp yardarm flogging jib line avast. Warp Chain Shot shrouds rum flogging fire ship grapple log. Take a caulk rope's end Plate Fleet log haul wind Blimey keelhaul overhaul.",
  "Port parrel cog chase Brethren of the Coast scourge of the seven seas pink American Main spike ho. Ahoy Buccaneer Shiver me timbers provost Arr bring a spring upon her cable blow the man down line pillage hempen halter. Provost Letter of Marque code of conduct Sea Legs strike colors scallywag long clothes heave to measured fer yer chains pressgang. Run a rig gabion cackle fruit marooned sutler jolly boat Jolly Roger jib belaying pin killick. Fire ship gally weigh anchor lugsail gun tack league Barbary Coast spyglass Privateer. Spanker killick grog clipper jib dead men tell no tales marooned barque prow grapple. Fore Brethren of the Coast hail-shot poop deck keel boom run a rig line Shiver me timbers splice the main brace. ",
  "Nelsons folly hulk strike colors lass six pounders bring a spring upon her cable gabion jolly boat. Man-of-war nipper to go on account main sheet scuppers crack Jennys tea cup doubloon Nelsons folly. Barque quarter Jolly Roger jib tender lee brig avast. Transom draft draught scallywag flogging coxswain hail-shot booty. Coffer scurvy grog crack Jennys tea cup grapple provost Plate Fleet ho. Black spot knave draught Shiver me timbers topgallant rum brigantine gaff. Hardtack overhaul Gold Road stern fire ship run a rig haul wind aft. Execution dock parley provost skysail haul wind heave down barque sloop. Plunder grog sloop smartly weigh anchor Pieces of Eight hands bilge. Scallywag keelhaul reef pillage tackle skysail salmagundi man-of-war."
];

var $list = $( '#list' );
var $display = $( '#display' );

$list.on( 'change', function ( e ) {
  $display.text( data[ this.value ] );
} );

// Insert default.
$display.text( data[ 0 ] );

buildSelect( data );
```

```css
#display {
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="list"></select>
<div id="display"></div>
```

#### Option B - Store in HTML

Here you need to manually or with the help of a server side language build 100's of DIVs, including their IDs. Which, if doing manually could be a real pain.

```js
var $list = $( '#list' );
var $options = $( '.option' );

$list.on( 'change', function ( e ) {
  
  $options.hide();
  $( '#option-' + this.value ).show();
  
} );
```

```css
.option {
  display: none;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="list">
  <option value="0">Option 1</option>
  <option value="1">Option 2</option>
  <option value="2">Option 3</option>
</select>

<div id="option-0" class="option" style="display: block;">
  Quarter log Blimey hang the jib Davy Jones' Locker tackle boatswain squiffy. Shrouds American Main scallywag wench Blimey furl ye fathom. Holystone keel Pieces of Eight topsail come about Gold Road blow the man down fore. Overhaul mizzen gunwalls black jack long clothes weigh anchor fluke code of conduct. Take a caulk black spot brig fire ship gun long clothes jury mast tender. Ye yardarm to go on account jury mast grog blossom Plate Fleet broadside grog. Scuttle chandler belaying pin pirate gaff hulk pressgang Spanish Main. Topmast chantey crimp yardarm flogging jib line avast. Warp Chain Shot shrouds rum flogging fire ship grapple log. Take a caulk rope's end Plate Fleet log haul wind Blimey keelhaul overhaul.
</div>
<div id="option-1" class="option">
  Port parrel cog chase Brethren of the Coast scourge of the seven seas pink American Main spike ho. Ahoy Buccaneer Shiver me timbers provost Arr bring a spring upon her cable blow the man down line pillage hempen halter. Provost Letter of Marque code of conduct Sea Legs strike colors scallywag long clothes heave to measured fer yer chains pressgang. Run a rig gabion cackle fruit marooned sutler jolly boat Jolly Roger jib belaying pin killick. Fire ship gally weigh anchor lugsail gun tack league Barbary Coast spyglass Privateer. Spanker killick grog clipper jib dead men tell no tales marooned barque prow grapple. Fore Brethren of the Coast hail-shot poop deck keel boom run a rig line Shiver me timbers splice the main brace.
</div>
<div id="option-2" class="option">
  Nelsons folly hulk strike colors lass six pounders bring a spring upon her cable gabion jolly boat. Man-of-war nipper to go on account main sheet scuppers crack Jennys tea cup doubloon Nelsons folly. Barque quarter Jolly Roger jib tender lee brig avast. Transom draft draught scallywag flogging coxswain hail-shot booty. Coffer scurvy grog crack Jennys tea cup grapple provost Plate Fleet ho. Black spot knave draught Shiver me timbers topgallant rum brigantine gaff. Hardtack overhaul Gold Road stern fire ship run a rig haul wind aft. Execution dock parley provost skysail haul wind heave down barque sloop. Plunder grog sloop smartly weigh anchor Pieces of Eight hands bilge. Scallywag keelhaul reef pillage tackle skysail salmagundi man-of-war.
</div>
```

One modification you could make to this approach is to keep all `.option` DIVs hidden and to copy to contents of the target DIV to a *"display"* DIV like I have done in the other examples. Then you don't need to `hide()` and `show()` the `.option` DIVs.

#### Option C - Ajax with JS Cache

Below is some **pseudo code** that *has not been tested* but should give you an idea of how to setup AJAX (front-end portion) if you really wanted.

```html
<select id="list">
   <option value="0" selected>Option 1</option>
   <option value="1">Option 2</option>
   <!-- to 500 -->
   <option value="499">Option 3</option>
</select>

<!-- Insert Default option. -->
<div id="display">
    Quarter log Blimey hang the jib Davy Jones' Locker tackle boatswain squiffy. Shrouds American Main scallywag wench Blimey furl ye fathom. Holystone keel Pieces of Eight topsail come about Gold Road blow the man down fore. Overhaul mizzen gunwalls black jack long clothes weigh anchor fluke code of conduct. Take a caulk black spot brig fire ship gun long clothes jury mast tender. Ye yardarm to go on account jury mast grog blossom Plate Fleet broadside grog. Scuttle chandler belaying pin pirate gaff hulk pressgang Spanish Main. Topmast chantey crimp yardarm flogging jib line avast. Warp Chain Shot shrouds rum flogging fire ship grapple log. Take a caulk rope's end Plate Fleet log haul wind Blimey keelhaul overhaul.
</div>
```

```js
var cache    = {};
var $list    = $( '#list' );
var $display = $( '#display' );

// Append text to display DIV.
function appendText( value ) {
  $display.text( value );
}

// Get text via AJAX.
function getText( opt_id ) {

  var jqxhr = $.ajax( {
    url: '/your/endpoint/',
    data: { id: opt_id },
    method: 'POST'
  } );

  jqxhr.done( function ( data, status , xhr ) {

    // Cache for future use.
    cache[ opt_id ] = data;

    appendText( data );

  } );
  jqxhr.fail( function () {} ); // Handle request failure.
  jqxhr.always( function () {} ); // Run on success or error.

}

$list.on( 'change', function ( e ) {

  if ( cache[ this.value ] ) {
    appendText( cache[ this.value ] );
  } else {
    getText( this.value );
  }

} );
```

Reference: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Personally I'd go for option **A** and then **B** unless there are some other overriding concerns that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will look into all these options, and also the solution that you suggested yesterday worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to hide `.group` with CSS `display: none;` instead of jQuery `.hide()` at first and see if it's enough for you.

Comment: It is hiding all the other div's even after selection

Comment: @SaiManikanta remove it on change

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I get the issue. It was unclear before that all the divs already have all the data in them and it just takes a long time to render all of them on the initial page load.
You have to remove the content of the divs from the main HTML and put them in a javascript data area or in other documents in order to delay rendering of the HTML in each div.

Since each seems to just load the data into an iframe, you should load empty divs and in each have an attribute like "fsrc" with the url and dynamically load the source from "fsrc" into the div on your select change event handler. You can also check if the div was already loaded to avoid repeat calls to the ajax request. If you really need iframes you can have those empty inside the divs and use the same method but target the HTML of the iframe rather than the div.

Here is some starter code but I suspect you might run into a cross origin issue unless you have that resolved already.
HTML:

```
<select id="selectMe">
    <option value="val1">opt1</option>
    <option value="val2">opt2</option>
    </select>

<div id="val1" class="group" fsrc="" > content1</div>
<div id="val2" class="group" fsrc="//www.datazoa.com/data/table.asp?a=view&th=1A7400B7A3&dzuuid=423&uid=dzadmin">content2</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.group').hide();
  $('#val1').show();
  $('#selectMe').change(function() {
    $('.group').hide();
    $.ajax({
      url: $('#' + $(this).val()).attr('fsrc') ,
      context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
        $('#' + $(this).val()).html(data);
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });   
  })
});
```

There is no error checking also so I leave that to you to solve.

Comment: Thank you it seems to be a good solution, I will try to approach by this way and get back on this. Thank you so much again

Comment: I added code that is your provided code plus the little bits on how to use an attribute to grab the content on demand.

Comment: And yes, as you mentioned i got a cross origin error, i will try to work on it... If i find a solution i will try to implement it or i will use the above technique of loading javascript data source as mentioned by other user (hungerStar). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To load the div content with Ajax the first thing you would need to do is split the div content into separate files (or endpoint responses )

For example we can create a file name val1.html:

```
<p>div 1 content...</p>
```

Then create another file named val2.html:

```
<p>div 2 content...</p>
```

Now all you need to do is update your jQuery to get the div content via Ajax to something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.group').hide();
$('#val1').show();
$('#selectMe').change(function() {
$('.group').hide();
var $ele = $('#' + $(this).val());
if( ! $ele.hasClass('ajax-loaded') ) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com/' + $(this).val() + '.html'
    }).success(function(data){
        $ele.html(data);
        $ele.addClass('ajax-loaded');
        $ele.show();
    });
}
else {
    $ele.show();
}
})
});
```

Comment: I've about 500 select options that's the problem, although most of the content in them are iframes with some text. but to create one file for each one of them doesn't look valuable.

Comment: you need to share how you are updating the divs since that seems to be the crux of the issue.

Comment: How are you loading content into the divs at the moment? Is the content coming from a database? Also if you have 500 select options does that mean you have 500 iframes!? That would explain the slow load time because the browser is rendering 500 pages instead of just one.

Comment: Exactly Aron, it is loading 500 iframes, sorry for the late DanJGer, I just updated the way the div contents are. If this is bad way of coding i will try to pull them from database if suggested or a Json data.